# Does closing golang channels also force goroutines to synchronize?

Tags: go

As stated in [The Go Programming Language book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134190440) (pg. 226):

> Communication over an unbuffered channel causes the sending and receiving goroutines to synchronize. Because of this, unbuffered channels are sometimes called synchronous channels. When a value is sent on an unbuffered channel, the receipt of the value happens before the reawakening of the sending goroutine.

Does the same happens for closing a channel? I mean, does the receipt of a closed channel always happen before the reawakening of the goroutine which just closed it?

I remember reading something related to it. I searched on the book but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing a channel does not force goroutines to synchronize like send on an unbuffered channel.

[The Go Memory Model](https://go.dev/ref/mem#chan) specification says:

> The closing of a channel is synchronized before a receive that returns a zero value because the channel is closed.

The goroutine that calls `close()` does not block waiting for another goroutine to receive a zero value.

A goroutine that sends a value to an unbuffered channel blocks until another goroutine receives the value.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks bro!

Answer (score 2):

Closing of a channel happens before the receive from a closed channel. That is, if a goroutine wakes up because of a closed channel, the close happened before that goroutine woke up.

So the answer to your question is "no": receipt of a close channel does **not** happen before the closing goroutine wakes up, because the closing goroutine never blocks. Closing of a channel is not a blocking operation.

Comment: What description is wrong? I didn't state anything about closing channels.

If you're talking about the quote, it's from the official Golang book and it says nothing about closed channels. It says about unbuffered channels. lol

Comment: I was talking about your question. I edited my answer to clarify